# SSIS Temp Table error

Tags: ssis

I have SP contain temp table and generating 4 column in the output
as
id,name,original and changed
the output need to save in flat file.

can anyone please suggest how to do it with Execute SQL Task.

i tried to do with oledb with data access mode as SQL command.but getting error 
0x80040E14.

may any one suggest something.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do it in an Execute SQL Task? You could use something like `xp_cmdshell 'BCP.EXE.......`

Comment: because its a part of SSIS Package

Comment: You should be able to put down a data flow and set the source to your SP. Did you try that?

Comment: Like this: http://sqlknowledgebank.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/ssis-ole-db-source-with-stored-procedure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing the answer from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1574990-364-1.aspx), you can use WITH RESULT SETS to tell the SSIS engine in advance what data will be returned by the stored procedure.

> With this procedure:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UseTempTable
> AS
> BEGIN
>     SET NOCOUNT ON;
>
>     CREATE TABLE #MyTable(WhoCares INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Whatever VARCHAR(99));
>
>     INSERT INTO #MyTable(Whatever) VALUES('Minger');
>     INSERT INTO #MyTable(Whatever) VALUES('Bonjour');
>
>     SELECT ColInt = WhoCares
>         ,  ColVarChar = Whatever
>         FROM #MyTable
>
>
> END;
> ```
>
> I would get an error in SSIS 2012 if I tried to use it as a datasource
>   in a dataflow.
>
> Before 2012, there were various tricks to show a "pretend" recordset
>   such as SET FMTONLY ON... SET FMTONLY OFF but they don't work in 2012.
>
> From [Phil's article](http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-execute-result-sets), we just need to specify our Data Flow datasource
>   as
>
> ```
> EXEC('EXEC dbo.UseTempTable') 
>     WITH RESULT SETS
>     ( ( ColInt INT NOT NULL, ColVarChar VARCHAR(99)) )
> ```

More information: [link](http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/metadata-discovery-ssis-2012-not-working-wtih-temp-tables-2012-08-08/)